# Bootstrap form not showing correct

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a bootstrap form which i am trying to make look like this:

```
http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-contact-form
```

But this is how it looks:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4018/
```

Comment: you use bootstrap 2 here not 3

Answer (score 1):

It's because the link to your bootstrap CSS in the fiddle using `@import`:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

is version `3.1.1` which is wrong version as currently your HTML markup are using Bootstrap classes that belongs to version `2.x`, so you need to remove above `@import` from your CSS and use version `2.2.2` like your working demo:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

You can include it from the `External resources` in the `jsFiddle` just like how you import Bootstrap JS version.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4019/)**

Comment: I have a question, on my website its using whole of the width. How can i reduce it? https://www.dropbox.com/s/h04z5twtauv6eee/test.png and make it look like its look in jsfiddle.

Comment: It's quite difficult to answer without seeing your code. Can you create a fiddle demo?

Comment: I see, the problem is why I copy it so fiddle it shows correct but in my web-browser it doesnt show like that: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4024/

My browser: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h04z5twtauv6eee/test.png

Comment: Please make sure that all the files of your page are linked properly

Answer (score 1):

The working link uses Bootstrap 2.x while the fiddle is using the Bootstrap 3.x

Try removing

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

and adding

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

then you get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4021/).